# How to get data from db in c#?

Tags: c#

I need get data from sqlite database, but I get this error:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'

Am I changing type of data in a bad way?

```
conn.Open();
string stm = new CustomQueries().GetUsersByName(this.searchedName, this.searchedSurname);

SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(stm, conn);
SQLiteDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (rdr.Read())
{
    this.personResults.Add(new Person(
                    (int)rdr["Id"],
                    (int)rdr["School_id"],
                    (int)rdr["Role_id"],
                    (string)rdr["Name"],
                    (string)rdr["Surname"],
                    (int)rdr["Study_year"],
                    (string)rdr["Identification_number"],
                    (string)rdr["Address"],
                    (string)rdr["Phone"],
                    (string)rdr["Email"],
                    (int)rdr["Age"],
                    (string)rdr["Birth_date"],
                    (string)rdr["Year_letter"]
                    ));
}

conn.Close();
```

My database structure is same as fields in code. Columns are of type `Text` or `int` in the database - again same as type in ()

edit>
Query:

```
 public string GetUsersByName(string name, string surname)
        {
            return "select * from user where name LIKE '%" + name + "%' and surname LIKE '%" + surname + "%'";
        }
```

DB User table structure

[image]

Comment: Please show us the `CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: And the query, that is actually sent to the db ...

Comment: i will update in a second

Comment: Is one of the column values `NULL`?

Comment: Please note that your query is VERY prone to SQL injection!

Comment: `return "select * from user where name LIKE '%" + name + "%' and surname LIKE '%" + surname + "%'";` Don't do that - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection .

Comment: The code you show, should not produce any problems, because only text columns are nullable. Please show also the code of the `new Person(...)` constructor. Maybe you are doing some casts there?

Comment: @derpirscher `null` and `dbnull` aren't the same - hence my question.

Comment: If you think the error is in the cast of the columns, put the various columns in variables, like `int id = (int)rdr["Id"]; int schoolId = (int)rdr["School_id"]; ...`. In this way you'll see exactly where the problem is.

Comment: I'd suggest using Dapper to avoid this kind of manual mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying to convert a value or an object to its string representation by using a casting operator . When you execute the program you will get " System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'."

The ToString() method is defined by the Object class and therefore is either inherited or overridden by all managed types. So, here we call its ToString method because it successfully covert an instance of any type to its string representation .

(int)rdr["Id"] Here is the problem.
you can use Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Id"]) to fix your problem.

Comment: Yes thsi fix the problem thx

Comment: @YoungL. This would _not_ fix the issues for int - but it will (kind of) for strings that are `NULL` in the database (although @Rakib's explanation of _why_ is wrong).